# Parent View element overlay child view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically I have view controller **(1)** used as a root view controller for holding a page view controller **(3)**. The view controller **(2)** is used for displaying page content. So ViewController 2 is child of ViewController 1.

[image]

Everything works perfectly fine but the  **view controller 2** is always over the **view controller 1** which actually is the default behaviour. Is it possible to revert that so the red image is over the green ?

Here is how I set subview and the childViewController:

```
  [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
  [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
  [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

[image]

You can see the problem here **view controller 2**'s image is over **view controller 1**'s image.

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand your view hierarchy,but you can run your application,and use the menu in Xcode

Debug->View Debugging->Capture view hierarchy

to figure out the view's hierarahy

and there is a method may be you can try

```
self.view bringSubviewToFront:subView
```